# Not Showing permeterized Method in view controller class which are declared and defined in NSobject class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a `NSObject` Class and I have declared parameterized methods in .h file and defined those methods in .m class. I imported the `NSObject` class in an other `view controller` and created a reference(object) of the `NSObject` class.
Now when i try to call the methods in this class through reference the methods are not showing in it.
Here are my code in Image![Code for above question][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5TUJ.png

Comment: post some code here for better understanding. where is image?

Comment: I have attached and Image in it, where i have given full coading @ismail

Comment: i see nothing here no link or image

Comment: I think Now your able to see my code in Image @ismail

Comment: try this [service getitemsbycatid .... to access methods you should use space after object i think you are using .(dot) there

Comment: I tried but it showing only non paramaterised mathod but not paramaterised methods @ismail

Comment: i didnt figure out any bug there once clean and then try

Comment: thanks for reply, even I tried by creating new project but same issue @ismail

Comment: Thanks @ismail, it's working after giving space instead of .(dot)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got solution by replacing Space after (nsobject)object instard of .(dot) operator

Comment: havent you checked the 5th comment,
try this [service getitemsbycatid .... to access methods you should use space after object i think you are using .(dot) there